# Mock a function called by a tested function of the same file with jest

Tags: jestjs

I have a file exporting two functions `a` and `b`, where `b` makes a call to `a`.

I would like to mock `a` test that when I call `b`, it calls `a` with some parameters, but since the two functions are in the same file, I can't find any way of doing this.

`functions.js`

```js
export const a = (x) => { a very complicated function };

export const b = (x) => a(x+1);
```

`functions.test.js`

```js
import { a, b } from './functions';

describe('b', () => {
  test('calling b calls a with x+1', () => {
    const fakeA = //mock function a ... don't know how to.
    b(1);
    expect(fakeA).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't do this. Either split them to different modules or test as one unit.

Comment: `a` is an implementation detail of `b`. In tests you don't even know that it exists. Or, if the documented behaviour of `b` depends on `a` then `a` should be provided as an argument to `b` (and you can provide a mock in the tests).

Comment: To reformulate my previous comment: assuming I have to use the function `b`, do I need to know anything about `a` (in order to use `b`)? Does `a` have some side effects I should care when I use `b`? If the answer is "no" then `a` is an implementation detail of `b` and the test you wrote in the question should be removed. It is not an use case, it does not help you develop `b`; it prevents you changing `b`'s implementation.

Comment: @axiac, well, in my real case, `a` should be called with a lot of parameters i don't want to mock, and it also has a lots of side effects like sending sms and emails. So I really need to test that `b` calls `a` with expected parameters, without calling the actual `a`.

Comment: It sounds like `a` does too many things. I guess `b` is more complex than it is described in the question but still, the fact that it calls `a` is just an implementation detail and not its outcome. Its outcome is the email, the SMS and possibly others. The use case should expect the function that sends the email to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research, I found 2 ways to achieve this :

- The first way is to call `exports.a` instead of `a` in the `b` function :

`functions.js`

```js
export const a = (x) => { a very complicated function };

export const b = (x) => exports.a(x+1);
```

`functions.test.js`

```js
import * as functions from './functions';

describe('b', () => {
  test('calling b calls a with x+1', () => {
    functions.a = jest.fn();
    functions.b(1);
    expect(functions.a).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});

});
```

- The second way is to change the prototype of `b` to accepts a function, defaulting to `a`:

`functions.js`

```js
export const a = (x) => { a very complicated function };

export const b = (x, a = exports.a) => a(x + 1);
```

`functions.test.js`

```js
import { a, b } from './functions';

describe('b', () => {
  test('calling b calls a with x+1', () => {
    const fakeA = jest.fn();
    b(1, fakeA);
    expect(fakeA).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Bringing this issue up again, with that first approach, how do I reset function a implementation to original function, because subsequent test that need original function think it as empty function per functions.a = jest.fn(); I have tried clearAllMocks, and resetAllMocks, and it does not reset

Comment: Though it solves the question author's issue, I don't think this is the correct answer as it requires changing actual code(functions.js) instead of testing code(functions.test.js). Always, tests should be modified to suite actual logic not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is using **jest.spyOn** method.

**jest.spyOn(object, methodName)**

> Creates a mock function similar to jest.fn but also tracks calls to
> object[methodName]. Returns a Jest mock function.

```
import * as functions from '../functions';


describe('b', () => {
  test('calling b calls a with x+1', () => {

    const fakeA = jest.spyOn( functions, 'a' );

    functions.b(1);

    expect( fakeA ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: are those files js or ts files?

Comment: It's not possible to spy on a function that is used in the same module it was defined.

Comment: It actually is possible to do what this answer is saying