# Jest mocking inside the same module

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm following this thread. [Mock a function called by a tested function of the same file with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933890/mock-a-function-called-by-a-tested-function-of-the-same-file-with-jest)

> functions.js

```
export const a = (x) => { a very complicated function };

export const b = (x) => exports.a(x+1);
```

> functions.test.js

```
import * as functions from './functions';

describe('b', () => {
  test('calling b calls a with x+1', () => {
    functions.a = jest.fn();
    functions.b(1);
    expect(functions.a).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

It works for the most part, except that if I have additional unit test after `describe(b)`, that required the original implementation of `a()`, it will still be treated as mock function, like let's say I want to unit test `a()`, it won't work because it is an empty function now. e.g

```
describe('c', () => {
  test('unit testing a will call something 3 times', () => {
    functions.a()
    expect(whatever.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
  });
});
```

any way to fix this?

Note:

I have tried the following, but it does not work

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});
```

The only way I can make it work is this, but this seems like really hacky?

```
const originalA = functions.a.bind({});

afterEach(() => {
  functions.a = originalA;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `spyOn`? It doesn't replace your implementation just chekcing what is happening with that function.

```js
import * as functions from "../functions";

describe("b", () => {
  test("calling b calls a with x+1", () => {
    const functionASpy = jest.spyOn(functions, 'a');
    functions.b(1);
    expect(functionASpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```